# Proof that the sequence of prime number is infinite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Can someone please tell me how to prove that there is no last prime number? I am familiar with Euclid's one, but I'm looking for a different way. I'm in 11th grade and I can do intermediate algebra and basic calculus.
Only a basic idea/guidelines would suffice.

Comment: Since, you have tagged it sequences-and-series, i will give you a hint along the same line. Try to think of a sequence of integers in which infinitely many terms(maybe all) are pairwise co-prime(relatively prime).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Some_recent_proofs                                      ....see,this must suffice...

Comment: Being in the 11th grade means you haven't been taught yet a variety of areas in math that can be used to prove this.  I'm hoping the idea suggested by @MosBlack will be elaborated into an Answer.

Comment: Likely not all the proofs there will be accessible to you, but still it should answer your question.

Comment: I saw a proof that involved defining the "height" of a number $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dotsb p_N^{a_N}$ by ${\rm height}(n)=a_1+a_2+\dotsb+a_N$, where the $p_i$ are prime. We then find contradictory lower and upper bounds for how many primes have height less than some number $h$.

Comment: The very first proof I came up with for the infinitude of prime numbers was Euler's proof (see the Wikipedia entry mentioned above by another user). To this day I still consider it more natural (although not simpler) than Euclid's proof.